# Can you list sites secured on a FIDO u2f USB key?

Tags: u2f

Is it possible to list sites (that have keys) stored on a FIDO u2f USB key?

If you need to migrate TOTP accounts you can go through the list of sites on your, for example, phone app one by one. How are you supposed to remember all the accounts you have secured with a u2f key when you replace it?

My particular u2f device is a Feitian NFC key.

Answer (score 1):

Note it in your password manager app. (Or wherever you store recovery data in case the TOTP or U2F device is lost or destroyed.)

Usually the key doesn't store anything at all – it only has a single master key baked in, and either uses it as a seed to [generate](https://developers.yubico.com/U2F/Protocol_details/Key_generation.html) per-site keys on demand (based on the domain name provided by the web browser), or to encrypt the keys and return to the website for storage. This has many advantages compared to persistent storage (unlimited capacity, no memory wear-out), so practically all manufacturers use one of those options.

The FIDO2 specification introduces optional "resident keys" which *are* stored on device, but it seems that [there is no feature in the protocol](https://github.com/solokeys/solo/issues/156#issuecomment-477682848) to list or otherwise manage the keys. The only actions are 'register', 'authenticate', and 'factory-reset the whole thing'.